# gfortran can't find library that IS there

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm having trouble linking my program to a library. I've never done this before so I'm probably doing something stupid, but as far as I can tell I'm doing the right thing. I need to link my program `foo.f90` to a library `libbar.a` which is in a directory elsewhere below my home directory. I enter the command:

```
gfortran -c foo.f90
gfortran -o foo foo.f90 -L/directory/of/library -llibbar.a
```

But this throws:

```
ld: library not found for -llibhealpix.a
```

Where of course `libhealpix.a` is the real library (rather than `libbar.a`)

Any ideas as to why this would occur?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `-lbar` (or perhaps `-lhealpix`, if that's the real library name).

`-lxyz` results in a search for a file named `libxyz.a`.   Consequently, if you specify `-llibbar.a` then the file needs to be named `liblibbar.a.a`.

You could also simply specify the path and full name of the archive file on the gfortran command line: `gfortran -o foo foo.f90 /directory/of/library/libbar.a`

Comment: thanks a million.
Strange why does the linker add 'lib' prefix and '.a' suffix to the input library name