# GNU Fortran cannot find library file although its physically there

Tags: dll, gfortran, linker-errors

I am trying to link a precompiled BLAS dll to a Fortran example, the linker refuses.

I read: 
[gfortran can't find library that IS there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753591/gfortran-cant-find-library-that-is-there) unfortunately what helped there didn't work for me.

Specifically:

```
gfortran  -o "Test2"  ./main.o   -l"C:/Users/abc/workspace/Test2/blasdyndbgx64.dll"
c:/Program Files (x86)/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Users/abc/workspace/Test2/blasdyndbgx64.dll
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test2] Error 1
```

The previous link I provided recommended to use the -l"entire/path/filename.ext", yet it still throws at me that error whatever I try. Obviously the file is there, 
dir to the path+filename finds the dll.

I guess that since compilers are not my strong side I am still missing something trivial.

Comment: what about -Ldirectory -llibraryname does it help?