# ld: library not found for -lSystem collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status gfortran

Tags: compiler-errors, gfortran, macports

I need to use the gfortran compiler using macports (path=/opt/local/bin) for installing a software, but when I try this, I get the following error

`ld: library not found for -lSystem collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status gfortran`
If my path is /usr/local/bin, then there is no problem in compiling any program using gfortran. Anyone familiar with this issue? I have searched and found no solution.

Comment: Not very sure but seems to be a path issue. `/usr/local/(bin|lib)` are in search paths by default. You may try adding `/opt/local/lib` in library path aswell or whatever meets your need. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753591/gfortran-cant-find-library-that-is-there) seems similar, you may want to look in it

Comment: @Mihir, thanks. If I add /usr/local/bin before the /opt/local/bin, it resolves this issue, but now the error changes to                                                               ```ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64```

Comment: "Seems" the library you are using is for 32 bit architecture, but apple removed support for it.

Comment: yes, I had to go to /usr/bin to install everything, thanks for the help!